# Divided differences polynomial $p[z, a_1, a_2,...,a_n]$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Let's consider complex points $a_1,a_2,..., a_n \in \mathbb C$, and polynomial $p$ of degree $\deg p \ge n \ge 1$. I want to prove that function $q$:

$$q(z) = p[z, a_1,a_2,...,a_n]$$

has to be polynomial of degree $\deg p - n$.

**My solution**

From mean value theorem, we know that:

$$\forall_{z \in \mathbb C} \exists_{\epsilon_z \in (\min(z, a_1,...,a_n), \max(z,a_1,...,a_n))}: p[z, a_1,...,a_n] =  \frac{p^{(n)}(\epsilon_z)}{n!}$$

Now, since $p$ is polynomial of degree $\deg p$, then $p^{(n)}$ will be polynomial of degree $\deg p - n$, and this is sufficient fact to say that $q$ has to be polynomial of degree $\deg p - n$.

Is my justification correct?

Comment: Do you know the expression of q(z) under the form of a complex integral ?

Comment: I don't know. But is my solution correct, or it has a problem in it?

Comment: The right side contains a polynomial of the correct degree, but why is it a polynomial in $z$? You can apply the Ruffini theorem on synthetic division repeatedly.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand your solution.